# HyperLogLog Bucket size restriction

Tags: algorithm, bigdata

In HyperLogLog the bucket size for 32 bit hashed data should be between 4 and 16 bit. This leads to m = 16, 32, 64, ..., 65536 with an error 1.04/sqrt(m). M = 2^(bucket size).

What is the reason for choosing m in this range?

Do we choose it like this because of the memory usage for the register array and the converges of the error against zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, the Hyperloglog algorithm works for any number of buckets which is a power of 2. However, most implementations add some restrictions. The bucket size is usually between 5 and 8 bits and also depends on the implementation.